# Divide by after Group query in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I can't quite figure this out. This query works, but I'd like to add a column that shows the percentage of the total.

```
SELECT f.name AS Acc., count(h.fair) AS Count
FROM holes h
JOIN fair f ON f.fair_id = h.fair
GROUP BY f.name
```

This results something similar to:

| Acc. | Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 4 |
| D | 5 |

I'd like to have it show

| Acc. | Count | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 25%. |
| B | 6 | 30%. |
| C | 4 | 20%. |
| D | 5 | 25%. |

Comment: @J Bree what flavor SQL are you using?

Comment: using phpmyadmin and MySQL Workbench. So far they seem to be matching on the queries that I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with *SQL Server*.

```
with t2 as (
           select   col1     as "Acc."
                   ,count(*) as "Count"
           from     t
           group by col1
           ) 
select      "Acc."
           ,"Count"
           ,concat("Count"*100/(select sum("Count") from t2), '%') as Percentage
from        t2
```

| Acc. | Count | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 25% |
| b | 6 | 30% |
| c | 4 | 20% |
| d | 5 | 25% |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f43A1LmS?hide=4)